# Heredar una función en Spark

Tags: function, herencia, scala, apache-spark

estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Spark y quiero poner a parte en una función la sección de acomoda campos para que desde esta clase solo mande a llamar dicha función
alguien tiene idea de como ?
de antemano gracias por su ayuda

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext


object tablaspark{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

--lee tabla
 println("Prueba de Spark con Scala")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("tablaspark").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate
  var query = "select cdelemen,dselemen as estatus_poliza from test_mrc.tablaorigen"

  val ktctget = spark.sql(query)

-- acomoda campos
          def get_schema(Dat: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame): String = {
            var fieldStr ="";
            Dat.schema.fields.foreach{f => 
                fieldStr += f.name + " " + f.dataType.simpleString + ",";
            }    
            return fieldStr
        }

    var fieldStr = get_schema(ktctget)

--escribe tabla 
    spark.sql("drop table if exists test_mrc.tabladestino")
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_mrc.tabladestino(" + fieldStr.substring(0,fieldStr.length()-1)+") STORED AS PARQUET")
    ktctget.write.format("hive").mode("append").saveAsTable("test_mrc.tabladestino")
  }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo bien qué es lo que pretendes ni cómo quieres limitar la _visibilidad_ de la función. Si el código fuente va a ser visible para todos, ¿cómo impedir que alguien lo copie y lo ejecute?

Comment: lo siento creo que no me explique bien.
la dinámica es que tengo 1 tabla de la cual generare 21 catalgos con la misma estructura pero con filtros diferentes, y para no estar escribiendo 21 veces la sección de "acomoda campos" mas de una vez pensé en crear una función en otro scala la cual pueda llamar de mi clase principal y así evitar unas lineas de código

Comment: Si entiendo bien, necesitas separar código en otro fichero, lo que se conoce como _crear paquetes_. En Java no se pueden meter funciones sueltas en un paquete, siempre se deben definir como un método asociado a una clase (inlcuso las expresiones lambda lo son). En scala se resuelve el problema con los llamados  _objetos package_. Échale un vistazo a la documentación: <https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/package-objects.html>

Comment: va que que va. te lo agradezco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tenes que hacer es crear un nuevo objeto y luego llamarlo utilizando el su nombre y el nombre del método al interior del mismo.

Ejemplo. Creo el Objeto GetSchema:

```
object GetSchema {
  // acomoda campos
  def get_schema(Dat: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame): String = {
    var fieldStr ="";
    Dat.schema.fields.foreach{f =>
      fieldStr += f.name + " " + f.dataType.simpleString + ",";
    }
    return fieldStr
  }
}
```

Luego los en el main para poder ver el resultado en los dos DataFrames:

```
object tablaspark{

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val df1 = Seq("12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
      "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
      "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com",
      "12 https://jhafi.com xyza@gmail.com").toDF("mycol")
    var fieldStr_df1 = GetSchema.get_schema(df1)
    println(fieldStr_df1)

    val df2 = Seq((0, "2016-07-02 12:01:40"),
      (1, "2016-07-02 12:21:23"),
      (1, "2016-07-02 13:22:56"),
      (1, "2016-07-02 13:27:07"),
      (0, "2016-07-02 13:30:12"),
      (0, "2016-07-02 13:40:34"),
      (1, "2016-07-02 13:57:07"),
      (1, "2016-07-02 14:08:07")).
      toDF("signal", "timestamp")
    var fieldStr_df2 = GetSchema.get_schema(df2)
    println(fieldStr_df2)
  }
}
```

Si lo creas en otro Paquete lo vas a tener que importar.

Comment: gracias, lo intentare
xD